# Why is Esperanto music so full of mistakes?

Tags: grammar

When learning Esperanto I listened a lot to Esperanto music, and sometimes I either had trouble understanding things or got slightly annoyed because of quite clear mistakes, mostly with where words get cut off. Why is this?

My main example is [Dancu, by Esperanto Desperado](https://www.vagalume.com.br/esperanto-desperado/dancu.html). Things like komencas in the beginning, which should be komenciĝas, or karesas sin kar' around the end.

Comment: Jam de pli ol dek jaroj dubo restas en mia kapo: kiel “Sonĝo” povas soni kvazaŭ “Sonjo” kaj “Ju” kvazaŭ “Ĵu” en rokbando kie Bertilo mem ludas? Persone – Du homoj: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzSxNrOE_2A

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The vast majority of Esperantists learn the language as an adult, and unless you are a voracious reader there are few opportunities for practice. Since we normally learn grammar through years of immersion, not instruction, for the most part it is only Esperantists of the academically gifted kind who can look at a page of text and instantly see the grammatical mistakes.

Obviously it is possible for writers to deal with this to a certain extent by asking other people to check their work. However, this is inevitably awkward and creatively constraining. My guess is that songwriters are less likely than most even to feel the need.

It should be remembered of course that the purpose of Esperanto is communication in an atmosphere of freedom and harmony. While obviously we would prefer that grammatical mistakes be few in number (and the grammar is simple for that reason) it is contrary to the spirit of the language to take too much offence at the innocent mistakes of others.

Comment: I think people often become fanatical about the defense of grammatical correctness and in the process trample peoples' attempts at true connection. If only we had to go through Esperanto grammar school as children to smooth over the community's most common errors, so we wouldn't have so much grammar policing during casual discussion. I understand the need to protect regularity across time and across cultures, but I think some leeway to let people express themselves comfortably from their heart without worry of being corrected instead of being listened to supports the _interna ideo_ as well.